# Magento checkout says there was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have problem with **checkout**, when i click to **place order** from magento onepage checkout it says

> "There was error processing your order, please try again later."

I don't know why this is happening. Tried changing log folder permissions and clearing the cache but not worked. This is my **exception.log**.

```
2017-01-03T13:32:19+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'The value of attribute "SKU" must be unique' in /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1354
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'The value of at...')
#1 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'The value of at...')
#2 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(830): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/validat...', Array)
#3 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(189): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->validate(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(1078): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->validate()
#5 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->quickCreateAction()
#6 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('quickCreate')
#7 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
2017-01-03T13:32:28+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'The value of attribute "SKU" must be unique' in /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1354
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/elements/public_html/drsilver.in/dr/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'The value of at...')
```

Comment: is an observer hooked to place order event or any extension you are using for checkout?

Comment: Thanks for your response kalyan.. i'm not using any extension for checkout.

Comment: 1. from the stack trace, it is evident that some script is trying to create or save the product. please find why this action is getting called "quickCreateAction" during checkout.
2. Other chance could be, it is trying to reduce the stock levels of the products but there are duplicate SKUs. Please check "catalog_product_entity" table for duplicate SKUs.